# Efficiency and Redundancy of a database schema of a freelancing website?

Tags: sql, database-design

For my Project I have decided to implement a freelancing website's database.
Here are my relations

Hirer(username,password_hash,rating) primary_key->username

Worker(username,password,rating) primary_key->username

skillset(skill) primary_key->skill

Worker_Skills(username,skill) primary_key->(username,skill) , forign-key(username from Worker and , skill from table skillset)

inbox(Sender,Reciever,message)

Job_posting(Job-id,Title,description,poster's_username,date)

Job_skills(Job-id,skill)

Applications(Application_ID,Job_ID,Applicant,details)

So , I am having some problem here. First one is , The inbox relation is not really anything , cause one can have multiple same message from the same center. Also, the resolution of skills like , Job-skill and Worker-kill , there is redundancy in Job-id and Worker-username. How can I solve the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask two questions (or state two problems) in the same question for it makes answering difficult.

Both the 'hirer' and 'worker' tables should have a numerical id as the primary key, not the username. As a result, each row of the 'WorkerSkills' table should hold two numbers: the id of the worker and the id of the skill. You have done this correctly with jobs - the primary key of the 'job-posting' table is an id and the 'JobSkills' table uses this id along with the skill id.

Then you can write a query which can display which users have the required skills for which jobs.